# View of activity_main.xml does not show up in Graphical Layout of activity_main.xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I am trying to include a view under a TextView, the TextView shows up in the graphical Layout but not the View. I have attached the code and the graphical layout. Can anyone please help me, whats the wrong and how can i solve it...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.dt_4000.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="DT-4000"
        android:textColor="#BA0"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="16dip"
        android:background="#F90"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: You should specify a width in dp for your view / match_parent

Comment: Set your textview width to `wrap_content`

Comment: android:orientation="vertical" in the linerlayout

Comment: beyond that if you want the view to be under the textview you should specify orientation:vertical instead of orientation:horizontal

Answer (score 5):

> Try this code it may solve your problem

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.dt_4000.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" 
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:text="DT-4000"
            android:textColor="#BA0"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dip"
            android:background="#F90"

            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your TextView has width: android:layout_width="match_parent"  it occupies the whole width and your LinearLayout has orientation="horizontal" which will place the views side by side (horizontally)...BUT the first view (TextView) is already taking all the space...as it has android:layout_width="match_parent"...so no space left for its buddy a.k.a. **@+id/view1**

To fix it, you can either change:

```
 <LinearLayout ...
     android:orientation="vertical" ....
```

OR

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" ....
```